# Using cmake options in generator expressions

Tags: cmake

I would like to use a cmake option inside a generator expression
in order to turn on a certain compile flag. From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) it is not clear to me how to achieve this.

I would like to write something like

```
option(MYOPTION " ... " OFF)
...
add_compile_options($<$<MYOPTION>:-lblas>)
```

which does not work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your example doesn't really specify a use case for this, and I think there are other ways of going about it (as well as `-lblas` being a linker flag not a compile option.) Just off of the information you provide, it looks like what you might want is:

```
option(MYOPTION "My Option" OFF)
...
add_compile_options($<$<BOOL:${MYOPTION}>:-lblas>)
#(or maybe you want?)
target_compile_definitions(YOUR_TARGET PRIVATE $<$<BOOL:${MYOPTION}>:-lblas>)
```

`$<$<BOOL:...>:...>` needs a variable to assist with evaluating (which `MYOPTION` fulfills. There are other logical expressions listed in the documentation that you may use.

Comment: CMake documentation for [add_compiler_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_compile_options.html) command explicitely says, that it can use generator expressions. In general, generator expressions are allowed whenever CMake docs say so.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @Tsyvarev. I will correct my answer.

Comment: @Cinder Biscuits Thank you for your answer. The -lblas example was indeed badly chosen. My usecase is for making option specific defines in the end. $<BOOL:${MYOPTION}>:...> works perfectly!

Comment: FYI, there is an open bracket missing in the answer's examples.