# What is the best way to use Source File switches with CMake

Tags: cmake

I would like to build a shared library. The lib has a source directory and some sub directories.

```
source 
  core.c
  sub1
    featrue1.c
  sub2 
    feature2.c
  sub3
    feature3.c
```

So I would like to add the lib to a project an would like to build and link the lib only with feature 1. And for an other build I would like to build it with feature1.c and feature2.c and so on ...

Which mechanism can I use for that in cmake. In Eclipse CDT it is something like 
Resource Configuration => Remove or Add to build.

Many thanks
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_library.html#object-libraries):

```
# first solution
add_library(feature1 OBJECT sub1/feature1.c)
add_library(feature2 OBJECT sub1/feature2.c)
add_library(feature3 OBJECT sub1/feature3.c)
if(conditions)
    add_library(my_shared_library SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:feature1>)
elseif(other_condition)
    # other version
endif()

# second solution
add_library(my_shared_lib SHARED
    common.c
    $<$<BOOL:${WITH_FEATURE1}>:sub1/feature1.c>
    $<$<BOOL:${WITH_FEATURE2}>:sub2/feature2.c>
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite with generator expression, but that's new for me.

Comment: How to understand/read that line: $<$<BOOL:${WITH_FEATURE1}>:sub1/feature1.c>

Comment: I took the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793464/using-cmake-options-in-generator-expressions). [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793464/using-cmake-options-in-generator-expressions) says it will substitute sub1/feature1.c if WITH_FEATURE1 is switched on, anyway nothing. I still don't understand why we need to put the variable in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for options to be passed to `cmake` upon configuration. You can define them like this:

```
option(WITH_FEATURE1 "Description of awesome feature (1)" ON)
option(WITH_FEATURE2 "Description of awesome feature (2)" OFF)
```

and query them later in your `CMakeLists.txt`,

```
if(${WITH_FEATURE1})
    add_subdirectory(sub1)
endif()
```

Now, your build can be configured as follows.

```
cmake -D WITH_FEATURE1=OFF -D WITH_FEATURE2=ON
```

while the default options (when invoking `cmake` without these parameters) are specified when calling the `option` method above.

Comment: Okay, but then I need to have a CMakeLists.txt in the sub I think.

Comment: Possible, but not mandatory. You can also do different things in the if/else block.